# Implementation of the Singleton pattern in Python

Tags: python, singleton

As answered brilliantly by agf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/1901076), a possible implementation of a Singleton in Python could be using this metaclass:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

However, I do not understand the use of `_instance`. I know it's a dict used to store instances indexed by their class. However, it is declared as a class attribute (`_instances = {}`), and it is used as an attribute of `cls` (`if cls not in cls._instances:`). How can the two be the same?

Comment: shouldn't `def __call__(...)` be decorated with `@classmethod`?

Comment: Well, if you decorate `__call__` with `@classmethod`, a `cls` attribute is a class attribute, as the parameter name would suggest.